# Is there a way to remove the comments left by json serializable in the .g file?

Tags: json, flutter, jsonserializer

[image]

When I do the command to auto generate the code, I get these comments, but in my company they are asking me to remove them, so I wanted to know if there is any way that they do not appear

Comment: you can remove comments, but dont touch the codes :). after generating files. btw i prefer having them in place.

Comment: Yes, I would also prefer to leave them, but the company tells me that they have to be removed, but if I manage to generate the code, I would have to delete them one by one and I have about 20 models @YeasinSheikh

Comment: well, you can dart-data Class generator extension

Comment: The policy should be that you shouldn't  commit generated code to source control.  If that still doesn't meet your company's policies, those policies should be changed.

Answer (score 0):

I found a easy way to do this while using `VScode`.

1. goto `searchBar`
2. type `//.*` on searchBar
3. check that `.*`
4. from where you like to remove comments, my case `lib/main` directory,
5. press `replace` icon

does it work for you ?

[image: solution]